# TypeError: element.prop is not a function - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, magento2.0.8

In product detail page I got below error in browser console at `app/code/Magento/PageCache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js`

> TypeError: element.prop is not a function
>
> .prop('href', element.prop('src'))

[here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/999/2) I found one fix, but after that one new error appear that is

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document" in `http://domainname/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/jquery.js`

**note:** In luma theme product detail page works fine without any fix in `page-cache.js`

can anyone have an idea about root cause of the problem?

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/999..ceck this

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers are making changes to vendor and pub/static files:

Copy this file into your theme:

```
/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js
```

And change

```
.prop('href', element.prop('src'))
```

To

```
.prop('href', $(element).prop('src'))
```

You may need to clear browser and Magento cache. And possibly deploy static content depending on your workflow.

Comment: This is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ankit was close.

Go to path and open `page-cache.js`

```
 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/
```

Change line 40 of `page-cache.js`

> .prop('href', element.prop('src'))

To

> .prop('href', $(element).prop('src'))

Comment: Never edit files inside the vendor directory. This suffers from the same issue as Ankit's answer, if you change this you will likely lose your changes in future upgrades.

Answer (score -1):

Go `pub/static/frontend/<theme>/default/en_US/Magento_PageCache/js` path and open `page-cache.js`

Change **line 40** of `page-cache.js`

```
.prop('href', element.prop('src'))
```

To

```
.prop('href', $(element).prop('src'))
```

Comment: Changing any files in `pub/static` is a waste of time as when you regenerate the static files you'll lose the fix.

Answer (score -3):

Run following command in your root folder of Magento setup to set permission in Magento 2 :

```
  chmod -R 777 pub/static
```

Comment: Should never set permissions to 777